# ffplay - How to display “pts_time=…” while playing the video?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, frame

I am a beginner in `ffmpeg` and need to know how to use `ffplay` in Linux to display the `pts_time` while the video is playing.

I'm interested in seeing the `pts_time` of each frame. So I can check if the adblock begins with an IDR frame.

In windows machine I use the following commands to identify if the adbock begins with an IDR frames (by using `pts-time` infos):

```
ffplay -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/Tools/ffmpeg/arial.ttf:text='%{pts}%{pict_type}':fontsize=(h/10):box=1:x=(w-tw)/2:y=h-(2*lh)" c:/video.ts

ffprobe -show_frames -show_entries frame=pts_time,pict_type,key_frame -select_streams v c:/video.ts | grep -E --after-context=5 --before-context=5 "49635.045689"`
```

I need the PTS time to be displayed as in the attached photo:
[video with pts-time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nONmS.png)

In Linux I am able to play the video with the command `pts-time` and with the help of VcXsrv Windows X Server to be able to access the graphical interface of the Linux server from my Windows PC.

and with the following `ffprobe` comand, I am able to see the frames details and the `pts_time` of each frame:

```
ffprobe -select_streams v -show_frames video.ts
*[FRAME]
media_type=video
stream_index=5
**key_frame=1** */* it is a IDR frame*
pkt_pts=4467154112
**pkt_pts_time=49635.045689** 
pkt_dts=4467155912
pkt_dts_time=49635.065689
best_effort_timestamp=4467154112
best_effort_timestamp_time=49635.045689
pkt_duration=1800
pkt_duration_time=0.020000
pkt_pos=2262204
pkt_size=46939
width=1280
height=1080
pix_fmt=yuv420p
sample_aspect_ratio=3:2
pict_type=I
coded_picture_number=21
display_picture_number=0
interlaced_frame=1
top_field_first=1
repeat_pict=0
color_range=tv
color_space=bt709
color_primaries=bt709
color_transfer=bt709
chroma_location=left
[SIDE_DATA]
```

Any idea?